# Regions of intersected hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a linear arrangement of hyperplanes in
>   $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathcal{B} := \bigcap_{h \in \mathcal{A}} h$.
>   Show that $ \mathcal{C} := \{ h / \mathcal{B} : h \in
>  \mathcal{A}\}$ is an arrangement of hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^n
>  / \mathcal{B}$ with the same number of regions as
>   $\mathcal{A}$.

I'm not really sure what $\mathcal{B}$ contain, maybe vectors? If e.g. I take the $\mathbb{R}^2$ and set $\mathcal{A}$ to the two hyperplanes along the two coordinate axis, woud $\mathcal{B}$ then (only) contain the point $(0,0)$? If I am right, then the idea behind this is trivial, as $\mathcal{C}$ wouldn't change the regions, as it just removes single vectors from as well the hyperplanes as the space, but how can I prove that formally?

[Edit] 
Question fixed as Andreas Blass suggested.

Comment: But if you take A to be two planes in 3-space, then B is a line. And if you take A to be 7 hyperplanes in 53-space, then B is, well, I don't have a clue what B is.

Comment: The quoted material would make a lot more sense is both occurrences of $\backslash\mathcal B$ were changed to $/\mathcal B$. The given arrangement $\mathcal A$ induces an arrangement in the quotient space obtained by dividing out the intersection of all its hyperplanes.

Comment: @AndreasBlass that might be, I copied it from someone with a very difficult handwriting. What would $/\mathcal{B}$ mean then?

Comment: If $V$ is a vector space (like $\mathbb R^n$ or any $h\in\mathcal A$)and $W$ is a subspace (like $\mathcal B$), then $V/W$ denotes the quotient space.  It consists of equivalence classes $[x]$ of vectors $x$ from $V$ under the equivalence relation that maks $[x]$ and $[y]$ equivalent iff $x-y\in W$.  Addition in $V/W$ is deined by $[x]+[y]=[x+y]$; similarly, for scalars $a$, one defines $a[x]=[ax]$.  (Of course, one must check that these operations are well-defined and make $V/W$ into a vector space.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass yes, you were right, thank you! I fixed the question